# Does editing a slow bullet imply a memory change?

Tags: slow-bullets

In the very end of the *Slow Bullets* novella, Scur, the protagonist, reveals something that implies her slow bullet might have been edited before being put in the prison ship:

> A year or two before he died, Prad told me that he had found an anomaly in my slow bullet readout. It had been a small thing, easily overlooked. I remember now that he had mentioned corrupted sectors, parity errors. It might have been nothing more than the sort of random corruption that had befallen the bullet during the centuries that we were frozen in hibo. 
> Or it might have been something else. A sign, perhaps, that the contents of my bullet had been deliberately altered before I ever entered the ship.
> That one history had been replaced by another.

What does this imply? As far as I understood, the slow bullet only stores information, it shouldn't affect memory at all. Scur seems to have memories of past events that were corroborated by the info in her slow bullet. If her slow bullet was edited, does it imply that her memory has been changed as well?

Does this 'edited memory' plot point involve Orvin at all?

Answer (score 3):

We may never get a solid answer for this, but I don't believe Scur's edited bullet at all involves Orvin. The slow bullets keep track of a person's activities, like a digital record, they don't actually hold the memories of the person. This is shown at the end of the story when

> all of the passengers with slow bullets on the ship erase their slow bullet records to hold pieces of the decaying digital information of the human race.

Perhaps Scur's slow bullet had been edited in the process of putting her on the prison ship.